# Django Post Request with custom Dict for Dynamic Survey

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have the following structure:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey('Survey')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
```

and Generate the form.
[image]

My Question is... How I get data of POST?

I try:

```
{% for question in survey %}
    <div class="control-group ">
        <label class="control-label" for="{{question.id}}" >{{question.id}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" value="{{question|answer:user}}" class="grd-white" name="answer" id="answer_{{question.id}}" />
        </div>
    </div>                                
{% endfor %}
```

But result is:

[image]

I need something like:

```
{"answers":{id_question_1:"text_answer_1",id_question_2:"text_answer_2",id_question_3:"text_answer_3" }}
```

example:

```
{"answers":{1:"A1",2:"A2",3:"a3"}}
```

Comment: Have you considered using form class to render forms?

Comment: yes, I tried, but without success!

Comment: What kind of problems did you have with form class?, since this is really the way to go..

Comment: Hello @mariodev [this is my case](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6ScVacD32w4MFdqdEZTTW11bTQ/edit?usp=sharing) how I can make a form for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Ops this image is landscape [link to image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6ScVacD32w4QmxOdUc2TEdTR3c/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

That is the only thing I could come up with:

template

```
name="answer_{{question.id}}"
```

views.py

```
dict([(k.split('_')[-1], v) for (k, v) in request.POST.items() if 'answer' in k])
```